# Binding Collection in wpf comboBox with mvvm (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to using mvvm pattern with wpf to create an interface for a project previously did in win form. 
In this project i have an object that contains some List<> that i have to show in real time on my interface with a combobox, the problem is that combobox don't change his values. I'm using the dll of mvvm fundation for implement NotifyPropertyChanged. I think to make some mistake but i don'y know where is it.

I've tried to do a simple code with only one list in viewmodel and without a model but the result doesn't change.

```xml
<Window x:Class="ProvaComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProvaComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Button Content="Generate" Command="{Binding Generate}"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding Clear}"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Word, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
//view Model
    class ViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        private List<string> _word;

        public List<string> Word
        {
            get { return _word; }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            _word = new List<string>();
        }
        public ICommand Generate

        { get { return new RelayCommand(GenerateExecute); } }

        void GenerateExecute()
        {
            _prova.Add("pippo");
            _prova.Add("pluto");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Word");
        }
        public ICommand Clear
        { get { return new RelayCommand(ClearExecute); } }

        void ClearExecute()
        {
            _prova.Clear();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Word");
        }
    }
```

```cs
//View: 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I think that the problem it's RaisePropertyChanged, but it work correctly with normal variables.
I've tryed also using ObservableCollection and it work, but i can't use it with real project.

(p.s. Its my first question in stack overflow, sorry if i did some mistake!)

Comment: You should really use an ObservableCollection (nomen est omen) or another collection type that is observable. Unlike an ObservableCollection, a simple List<T> is not observable, so the Combobox cannot know when items are added to, removed from or replaced in the list _after_ the list has been bound to the ComboBox. If you can't use ObservableCollection, though luck (no, really, i sincerely question the requirment that forbids you to use an ObservableCollection. It doesn't really make sense to me, and i suggest you are working on either eliminating or circumventing that strange requirement)

Comment: Are you saying RaisePropertyChanged(“Word”) in GenerateExecute() isn’t causing the ComboBox to update its dropdown with the new items?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that RaisePropertyChanged(“Word” ) isn’t causing the ComboBox updating.

Answer (score 0):

use `ObservableCollection` like that

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Word
        {
            get => _word;
            set
            {
                _word= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Word");
            }
        }
```

and change the binding mode in your combobox xaml code from OneWay to TwoWay or just remove it to be something like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Word}" />
```